# Advanced date filter in excel

Tags: excel, date, filter

I like to ask you for help with my problem in excel :)

My data looks like this:

[image: data]

Basicly event name; start-date; and end-date.

Events can last anything between 1-365 days and I would need to create filter, which would show me all events, which has been active between the choosen period of time.

For example if my filter setting would be:
"show me all events, which might be active between 18.1.2020 - 20.1.2020"

Outcome from my dataset should be:

Event2;Event3;Event4

Here is better description of problem in excel.
[Link to xlsx file](http://mysharegadget.com/664033462)

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Filter()` function is best fit for you with `Excel365`.

```
=FILTER(B3:D7,((C3:C7>=C11)+(D3:D7>=C11))*((C3:C7<=C12)+(D3:D7<=C12)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Harun, 

unfortunately, I am still on 2016 version of excel, so I cant test it. 

Anyway is there a way how to return all the values between:
Start date  and End date? I am thinking maybe some array formula might be able to do it.  

Something like loop: 

`X = Start date 
Do Until X = End date
X = X + 1 
loop`

Or other solution :)